# Coulomb terms of Thomas Fermi model is a symmetric decreasing function

Tags: analysis, mathematical-physics, decreasing-rearrangements

In the proof of theorem 2.12 in Thomas-Fermi and related theories (Lieb) it is stated that: if $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\rho\leq Z $$ then $$f(x)=Z \vert x\vert^{-1}- \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\frac{\rho^{*}(y)}{\vert x-y\vert}dy$$ is symmetric decreasing function,  where $\rho^{*}$ is  the symmetric , decreasing rearrangement of $\rho$ and $Z>0$.  I can not show the part of the decreasing monotony.
 Any help would be appreciated, thank you.
Note:

> Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a Borel set of finite Lebesgue measure. They define
>   $A^*$ to be the ball centered at 0 with the same measure that
>   $A$.
>
> The symmetric-decreasing rearrangement of a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is then defined by
>
> $$f^*(x):=\int_0^{\infty} \chi_{\{|f|>t\}^*}(x)dt,$$
>
> by comparison to the "layercake" representation of $f$, namely
>   $$f(x)=\int_0^{\infty} \chi_{\{f>t\}}(x)dt.$$